.NET 8 exposing to VB6 using COM
.NET 8 exposing to VB6 using COM
Issue
We have a large application with a lot of GUI code in VB6 and the logic mainly in .NET Framework 4.7.2 libraries. Now we want to move to .NET 8 and having difficulties exposing the libraries to VB6 using COM:

Set oObject = New COMObject is not working (class is empty in VB6 Object Browser)
Events are not exposed

Both issues seem to be related to exposing the classes with(out) the [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] attribute.
We are using dscom32 (tlbexport/tlbregister) and are aware of CA1408.
How do we overcome our issues (1 and 2) without rewriting a lot of VB6 code in a type-unsafe way and without creating an extra .NET Framework 4.7.2 layer?
.NET 8 Project file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <EnableComHosting>True</EnableComHosting>
        <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="ServerUsage" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Message Importance="High" Text="Register:%0a    regsvr32.exe &quot;$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)$(ComHostFileName)&quot;" />
        <Message Importance="High" Text="Unregister:%0a    regsvr32.exe /u &quot;$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)$(ComHostFileName)&quot;" />
    </Target>

</Project>

.NET 8 code
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestCOM
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("A5447236-9520-4596-B4C6-D40175EBDA10")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface ITestCOM
    {
        string GetString();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("3FCD4A46-F73D-495F-9DE3-85D50924ED06")]
    //[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class TestCOM : ITestCOM
    {
        string ITestCOM.GetString() => "Test";
    }
}

VB6 Code
Sub Main()

    ' This is not working:
    ' Dim oTest As TestCOM
    ' Set oTest = New TestCOM
    '
    ' Requires ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual
    '
    ' dscom32 tlbexport "%cd%\Test.dll"
    ' -> Failed to export type library. Dual class interfaces not supported!
    
    ' This is working:
    Dim oTest As ITestCOM
    Set oTest = CreateObject("TestCOM.TestCOM")
    Debug.Print oTest.GetString()

End Sub

New code based on Seva Alekseyev
Both issues are now solved for me.
.NET 8 code
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestCOM
{
    internal delegate void OnGetStringCOM(EventArgsCOM args);

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("E6BCA6A0-70F3-4218-B344-3632F638D51A")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface IEventArgsCOM
    {
        string Message { get; set; }
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("77414A17-1CA5-4E45-940E-F26C8F50BE3E")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class EventArgsCOM(string message) : EventArgs, IEventArgsCOM
    {
        public string Message { get; set; } = message;
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("891E4AFB-8CD3-4611-80F6-F3AC755EF3B4")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface ITestCOMEvents
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        void OnGetStringCOM(EventArgsCOM args);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("A5447236-9520-4596-B4C6-D40175EBDA10")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface ITestCOM
    {
        string GetString();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("3FCD4A46-F73D-495F-9DE3-85D50924ED06")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ITestCOMEvents))]
    public class TestCOM : ITestCOM
    {
        private event OnGetStringCOM OnGetStringCOM;

        public string GetString()
        {
            OnGetStringCOM?.Invoke(new EventArgsCOM("test raised"));
            return "test returned";
        }
    }
}

VB6 Code
Private WithEvents moTest As Test.TestCOM

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set moTest = New TestCOM
    
End Sub

Public Function PrintString()

    Debug.Print moTest.GetString()
    ' test returned

End Function

Private Sub moTest_OnGetStringCOM(ByVal args As Test.IEventArgsCOM)

    Debug.Print args.Message
    ' test raised
    
End Sub


You certainly don't need .NET Framework back in town to make VB6 talk to .NET 8. Do you have a fully reproducible compilable project somewhere so we don't lose time in details?

VB6 is Visual Basic 2006 before the Net Library combined Visual Basic and c# into a single library Net 3.0.  Microsoft attempted to make Active X obsolete.  So any Active X object you had to manually register using Regsrv32.

Microsoft attempted to obsolete ActiveX components starting with VB5 (~2005). Microsoft was replacing Win95 with XP and also getting ready to release Net 3.0 (quickly replaced with Net 3.5 due to large number of bugs).  At work, we tried to update from Win95 to XP and found we could not get ActiveX working.   We had a spinner control that was ActiveX and Net did not have an equivalent object.  We found solution was to manually install ActiveX libraries using Regsrv32.

@jdweng I think you have some dates mixed up there. VB5 was released in 1997 and very much supported ActiveX. VB6 was released in 1998. .NET 3.0 was released in 2006, many years after XP which was in 2001. ActiveX still works in Windows 11 if you really want. There was no version of VB.NET released in 2006, there was in 2005, and that was also termed VB8.

In my experience there is nothing wrong with using AutoDual if you are consuming the libraries yourself. If you always rebuild both client & server together use AutoDual and make your life easy. I'm speaking from .NET framework .experience, I have not tried dscom.

Is using regsvr32 the problem? In .NET framework you could never do that - VS or msbuild did that instead.  If dscom is producing .TLB files you should be referencing those from VB6 (not the DLLs).  I'm not sure what dscom does to register the classes that the TLB specifies however?

Seems that dscom does not support AutoDual - https://github.com/dspace-group/dscom?tab=readme-ov-file#limitations

And instead of regsvr32, sounds like you should use dscom tlbregister command.  https://github.com/dspace-group/dscom?tab=readme-ov-file#usage

Try annotating the class (not the interface!) with [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]. You don't want .NET to autogenerate a COM interface for the class also - it will get in the way.
For the interface, try [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)] or InterfaceIsIDispatch. I don't recall if VB6 can consume custom (i. e. not derived from IDispatch) interfaces, but IDispatch based automation was always Visual Basic's native mode of operation.
Then rebuild, then reestablish a reference from the VB project. I don't think VB6 picks up typelib changes on build.

there are two types of objects 1) Early binding 2) Late Binding.  Early Binding object are resolved during compiling.  Late Binding object are resolved at Run Time. Solution looks like it is using Late Binding.  Using Regsrv32 would use Early Binding and making libraries Com objects that can get compiled into project.

Btw, VB6 can consume custom IUnknown derived interfaces.
